# Jquery trigger animation on each click (issue)

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I need to trigger the animation on each button click not toggling the button class as I have on my snippet bellow:

I tried with `addClass()` and `removeClass()` similar methods, but it doesnt work as expected, here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button[class*='navbar-toggler']").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("my-animation")
    });
})
```

```css
@keyframes my-animation {
 16.65% {
  transform: translateY(8px);
 }

 33.3% {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
 }

 49.95% {
  transform: translateY(4px);
 }

 66.6% {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
 }

 83.25% {
  transform: translateY(1px);
 }

 100% {
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

.my-animation {
  animation-name: my-animation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navToggler" aria-controls="navToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use setTimeout funtion for remove my-animation class and use

```
.navbar-toggler{
outline:0!important;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(!$("button[class*='navbar-toggler']").hasClass('my-animation')){
    $("button[class*='navbar-toggler']").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("my-animation");
        setTimeout(function(){  $("button[class*='navbar-toggler']").removeClass("my-animation"); }, 1000);
    });
    }
})
```

```css
@keyframes my-animation {
 16.65% {
  transform: translateY(8px);
 }

 33.3% {
  transform: translateY(-6px);
 }

 49.95% {
  transform: translateY(4px);
 }

 66.6% {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
 }

 83.25% {
  transform: translateY(1px);
 }

 100% {
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

.my-animation {
  animation-name: my-animation;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

.navbar-toggler{
outline:0!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navToggler" aria-controls="navToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>
```

Comment: And why it doesnt work if you use $(this).removeClass() instead of $("button[class*='navbar-toggler']").removeClass()??

Answer (score 0):

this may help you 
using

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button[class*='navbar-toggler']").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("my-animation");
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#YourId').removeClass('my-animation');
            }, 200);
    });
})
```